# Angular: Behavioral Subject's value object is not extensible

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to find the best way to update a value of a Behavioral Subject.

When I try to set an object's attribute value, I'm getting TypeError: Cannot add property sport, object is not extensible.

```
  selectSport(sport: Sport){
    this.match$.getValue().sport = sport;
  }
```

What is the best way to update Subject's data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an example how it should be implemented:

```
selectSport(sport: Sport) {
  this.match$.next({ ...this.match$.getValue(), sport });
}
```